# Bernoulli's solution of Riccati equation $y' = b t^{n} + cy^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've been studying Riccati differential equation of the form: $y' = b t^{n} + cy^2 $ where b, c are constants. This is the one that was studied by J. Riccati himself and was solved by D. Bernoulli for all cases that $n = \frac{4k}{1 \pm 2k}$ where $k = 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,...$ for which the solutions are expressed in terms of elementary functions.

From a youtube vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIEQMsbkpfI, the method has been explained quite well. However the vid does not provide examples except for the case when n = -2. I thought the substitution $y = \frac{w}{t}$ was the way to go and then tried it with the equation: $y' = t^{-4} + y^2$ where n = -4 corresponding with k = 1 and $n = \frac{4k}{1 - 2k}$. So:

Solve \begin{align}y' = t^{-4} + y^2 & \text{, (1)}\end{align}

Substitution: \begin{align}y = \frac{w}{t} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{w}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t} \frac{dw}{dt}\end{align}

The Eq.(1) becomes: \begin{align}-\frac{w}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t} \frac{dw}{dt} = t^{-4} + \frac{w^2}{t^2}\end{align}

Multiply both sides by $t^2$ : \begin{align}-w + tw' = t^{-2} + w^2 \Rightarrow tw' = w^2 + w + t^{-2}\end{align} From this point I found it very confused to continue.

I've tried to read some classic text like *Ordinary differential equations and Their solutions by G.M. Murphy* but I failed to understand what is written in the book. Maybe I made a mistake with the substitution $y = \frac{w}{t}$. I would appreciate any help from you guys for solving the Eq.(1) or for explaining how to apply Bernoulli's method for Riccati equation in general. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) seems to be suggesting a different methodology

Comment: Which page did u read? Is it the page about general Riccati eq: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation ?

Comment: i linked to the page i read, yes - it's the one you suggest

Comment: The general method presented in the wiki page doesn't really help with this particular Eq(1). I have tried b4 posting the question here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{1}{\xi} \\ y=-\frac{1}{c}(\xi-\eta\xi^2)
\end{array}\right.$, then the equation becomes
$$(-\xi^2)(1-2\xi\eta-\xi^2\frac{d\eta}{d\xi})=-cb\xi^4-\xi^2(1-\xi\eta)^2\Rightarrow \frac{d\eta}{d\xi}=-cb-\eta^2.$$

In particular, when $b=c=1$, the solution is
$$\eta=\tan(C-\xi)\Rightarrow y=\frac{\tan(C-\frac{1}{t})}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: This is correct. I have checked by plotting the result solution in Geogebra. Damn, Mathematica gives me the dull solution: y[x] -> (-(x + C[1]) Cos[1/x] + (-1 + x C[1]) Sin[1/x])/(x^2 (Cos[1/x] - C[1] Sin[1/x])). I wasted 2 days. Thank u very much, @Liufeng Yang. Btw, can u please explain how did u know which is the right substitution ?

Comment: @thanh.phan95  For the special case $\frac{dy}{dt}+y^2=at^m$, Liouville proved that it can be solved analytically iff $m=0,-2,\frac{-4k}{2k+1},\frac{-4k}{2k-1}$. In short, if $m=0$, it is separation of variables; if $m=-2$, it turns to separated after transforming $t=\xi,\ y=\frac{\eta}{\xi}$; if $m=\frac{-4k}{2k+1}$, it turns to the case $m'=\frac{-4k}{2k-1}$ after transforming $t=\xi^{\frac{1}{m+1}},\ y=\frac{a}{m+1}\eta^{-1}$; if $m=\frac{-4k}{2k-1}$, it turns to the case $m'=\frac{-4(k-1)}{2(k-1)+1}$ after transforming $t=\xi^{-1},\ y=\xi-\eta\xi^2$.